# Sharepoint 2013 discussion board sending email to creator when people reply to discussion

Tags: email, discussion-board

I am working on sharepoint 2013 discussion board, the scenarios is when ever any user replies to a discussion, an email is sent to the author. I have checked there is no workflow associated with the discussion and no alerts are defined.

I know this is not an OOTB option, or may be I am wrong, what other options are available to send notification to the author on a discussion board.

Thanks,
Moss

Comment: Do you have full access on site?

Comment: Yes i have full access

Comment: Did you check if workflow is associated with Content type ?

Comment: surprisingly no workflow at content type level as well...any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If high authority person has set alert, it will not show in `Manage Alert` of Discussion board list.

To see alert,

1. Go to Site Settings > User Alerts.
2. Select user from dropdown `Display alerts for`
3. Update it

Now check here is any alerts for discussion. If yes, remove it. [image]